# Copying the files - for each date from source into target directory with same date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have prepared a shell script to copy the files from local to hdfs but one problem.  I have created the directory for each day of the current month i.e. June.  I am looking for some way to copy the file for the respective date into the respective hdfs folder

For ex -

```
Test_2G3G_20210601* file to 20210601 folder in hdfs
Test_2G3G_20210602* file to 20210602 folder in hdfs etc
```

Is there any way to do this using shell script?

Comment: Sure there is.  You need to loop on the days, and for each day, create the directory and move the files with the day's date into the directory you have created.  Look at `for` loop, `mkdir`, `cp`.  Get started, research, read on bash scripting.  For your questions, read [ask] and [mcve] for the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
dstpath=$2
files=$(ls $path)
for file in $files
do
IFS='.' read -ra fs <<< "$file"
fname=${fs[0]}
filename=$(echo $fname | awk -F '\_' '{print $3}')
ymd=${filename::8}
echo "ymd:" $ymd
if [ -e $dstpath$ymd ]
then
        echo "exsits"
else
        echo "mkdir"
        mkdir -p $dstpath/$ymd
fi
cp $path/$file $dstpath/$ymd/
done
```

note: the two args should **NOT** end with `/`: use`/home/user/test` not `/home/user/test/`

old answer:
I write a script`my_copy.sh`, it works well for me.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
dstpath=$2
files=$(ls $path)
for file in $files
do
IFS='.' read -ra fs <<< "$file"
fname=${fs[0]}
ymd=${fname: -8}
cp $path/$file $dstpath/$ymd/
done
```

**Usage**

```sh
$ ls /home/user/test
Test_2G3G_20210601.pdf
Test_2G3G_20210602.csv
$ ls /home/user/dst
20210601
20210602
$ ./my_copy.sh /home/user/test /home/user/dst
```

Comment: There is a slight change in the filename now :   1. Attach_2G3G_20210523051106_662_0714.txt_ready
2.  Attach_2G3G_20210524051406_776_0715.txt_ready

Comment: @RohitChawla, try the newest script.